# Is Glimpse.MVC able to work with HttpContext.Current.Session variables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, glimpse

I'm wondering if the package Glimpse.Mvc5 (1.9.0) http://getglimpse.com/ is able to work with `HttpContext.Current.Session` variables.

For example when I store the current language in session `HttpContext.Session['CurrentUILanguage']`, if I enable Glimpse, it always shows me that Session is null, otherwise when glimpse is disabled everything works great.

Here is the sample code of my viemodel:

```
public class VmCulture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public CultureInfo CultureInfo { get { return new CultureInfo(Symbol); } }
}

public class SiteSession
{
    public static VmCulture CurrentUICulture
    {
        get
        {
            return (VmCulture)HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUICulture"];
            // here I get it Null when enabling Glimpse
        }
        set
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture=new CultureInfo(value.Symbol);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(value.Symbol);
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(value.Symbol);
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(value.Symbol);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUICulture"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

### Update 1: Added the usage of SiteSession.CurrentUICulture

Suppose there is a **BaseController** class where I use the `protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)` for checking each request and persisting the current language.

Here is a sample code (simplified):

```
 protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
 {
     if (requestContext.HttpContext.Session["Languages"] == null)
     {
         //1. Get cultures from DB and add them to Session["Languages"]
         //2. Get from Request the culture parameter and add it to Session["CurrentUICulture"]
         //3. Set the current culture through SiteSession.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;

     }
     else
     {
         //1. Check whether the current language did not change
         //2. Set the current culture through SiteSession.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
     }
     base.Initialize(requestContext);
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean with "it always shows me that Session is null"? Normally there is a Session tab that shows you all the session information available. Though this is independent of Glimpse.Mvc

Comment: Normally yes, but when running the project with debug="true" the application raises an exception saying that Session is null("Remark here! The Tabs that are you talking about still show the correct session information"). Seems that glimpse is running in another instance or something, out of the current HttpContext

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace or so that shows when the exception is thrown? Could it be that the static `CurrentUICulture` is used in a property of an instance that is being serialized?

Comment: Yes, sure: ` StackTrace:
       at TestProject.ViewModel.ViewModels.Common.SiteSession.get_CurrentUICulture() in e:\Repositories\TestProject.ViewModel\ViewModels\Common\VmCulture.cs:line 21 ` which is exactly the line where i've commented in my question

Comment: Just to make sure I get it, but is the `SiteSession` class with the static `CurrentUICulture` property stored in a file named `VmCulture`?

Comment: Could you otherwise extend your sample with the code that is actually making the call to that `CurrentUICulture` property? Is it used as a parameter to a view or as a modelbound action parameter? Currently it is hard to see where Glimpse kicks in in the whole picture as the stacktrace only shows an error starting in `VmCulture` accessing the `SiteSession.CurrentUICulture` somehow, but there is no indication on where that `VmCulture` is coming from.

Comment: You're right, sorry. In a couple of minutes I'll add some explainations.

Comment: There seems still to be something crucial missing. From what I see in the `Initialize` method is that you only seem to do sets of `SiteSession.CurrentUICulture` and the error you get is when getting the `SiteSession.CurrentUICulture`. Can you create a small reproducible case? With that I mean: Have the minimum of code that when run, is giving the exception. So we need at least code in the `if` and `else` branch doing something with `SiteSession.CurrentUICulture` and one Controller class inheriting from that `BaseController` class together with a url describing how that controller is called.